# Distributed Mesh Processing with Hadoop

Tags: mesh

Is there a library to do mesh processing (slicing, repairing, etc.) on big models in a distributed way using Hadoop?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe your problem or need and the steps, if any, you've taken to solve it. See also [What topics can I ask about here?](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)